# Most Recent Coins added to CoinGecko

Tags: api, web-scraping, coingecko

I am trying to get the most recently added coin added to Coingecko. Any ideas which API to use or how to achieve this.

Ideally I am trying to get this in near realtime.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe how do you try to get the most recently added coin added to Coingecko? What endpoints do you reuse from the API docs at https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation?

Comment: Thanks, I am using Coins/List which does get all of the coins but I can't see date added or a way to sort by date added.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the name of the latest coins directly from https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added and then use CoinGecko API to search info by name.

In Python:

```
import requests

# get all coins listed on CoinGecko
coins = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list').json()
# extract the name of the latest coins
r = requests.get('https://www.coingecko.com/it/monete/recently_added')
for line in r.text.splitlines():
    if '<td class="py-0 coin-name" data-sort=' in line:
        name = line[len('<td class="py-0 coin-name" data-sort=')+1:-2]
        print(name)
        # then search coin in the list retrieved above
        for coin in coins:
            if coin['name'] == name:
                r = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/'+coin['id'])
                print(r.json())
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! It may be susceptible for web changes, but it works quite well. I wrote a little script to track newly listed tokens this way. [NewTokenTracker](https://github.com/rlf89/New-token-tracker) If somebody will be looking for this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Coingecko provides a direct API to retrieve recently added coins. For your development purposes, you can definitely try web scraping.

> https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added